# Why does cppcheck reports "Member variable is not assigned a value"?

Tags: c++, cppcheck

Consider this code:

```
class PrivateData
{
public:
    PrivateData() : m_attr(0) {}

    PrivateData& operator=( const PrivateData& data )
    {
        if ( &data != this )
        {
            m_attr = data.m_attr;
        }
        return *this;
    }

private:
    int m_attr;
};

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() : m_data( new PrivateData() ) {}
    ~MyClass() { delete m_data; }

    MyClass& operator=( const MyClass& data )
    {
        if ( &data != this )
        {
            (*m_data) = data.privateData();
        }
        return *this;
    }

    inline const PrivateData& privateData() const { return *m_data; }

private:
    PrivateData* m_data;
};
```

Why does cppcheck reports me?

> Member variable 'MyClass::m_data' is not assigned a value in 'MyClass::operator='.

Is it safe to disable the warning here?

Note: Removing `if ( &data != this )` has no effect.

Comment: It means you're in the class assignment operator, yet the member `m_data` is not changed. It retains its current value (an address), which for pointers is *frequently* a potential bug for assignment operators. I realize this is likely a mcve, because honestly it makes little sense for that member to be dynamic in the first place, given only this code.

Comment: Why is `m_data` pointer to begin with? Is `MyClass` a resource handler? If it isn't, `m_data` should not be a pointer. If it is, its semantics are probably broken.

Comment: Btw, if this is supposed to be a resource handler, you are trying to implement the proposed [`std::clone_ptr`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3339.pdf). Afaik, it was rejected because it was not possible to give it useful copy semantics. (E.g, you'd want `a == b` to hold after `a = b`, but you'd also want `a == b` iff the two pointers point to the same object.)

Comment: @BaummitAugen: `PrivateData` is meants to hide class attributes from client who will use the `MyClass` object. Basically, client has the `MyClass` definition but not `PrivateData` definition. Thus, attribute needs to be a pointer.

Comment: That's the [PImpl-idiom](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl). There should be many resources available on how to do that properly, no need to reinvent that yourself.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Fine, but this does not really answer my question....;-) Looks like the warning is not relevant here...I don't see why cppcheck reports a warning.

Comment: If that was supposed to be an answer, I would have posted it as an answer. ;)

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Makes sense ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a false positive in `cppcheck` indeed. The common solution is to add `// cppcheck-suppress operatorEqVarError` before the definition of `operator=`.